# if statement always returning false

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload = function() {

    var colors = [

        "rgb(255,0,0)",
        "rgb(0,255,0)",
        "rgb(0,0,255)",
        "rgb(182,12,235)",
        "rgb(166,212,166)",
        "rgb(242,123,72)"
    ]

    var pickedColor = colors[3];

    var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");

    colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

    var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {

        //coloring each square through colors array

        squares[i].style.background = colors[i];

        //listening for a click to compare if true

        squares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

            var clickedColor = this.style.background;

            var op = "rgb(182,12,235)";

            if (pickedColor == clickedColor) {
                alert("true");
            }
        });
    }
};
```

I don't know why my if statement is not working when I compare pickedColor with ClickedColor using the "===" comparison operator I have tried alerting, they both are the same values but when I compare this if statement always returns false:

```
if (pickedColor == clickedColor) {
    alert("true");    
}
```

I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: should probably be `this.style.backgroundColor` - also you cannot rely on browsers to give you color style information in any particular format. They vary.

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify([pickedColor, clickedColor]))` to find out why they don't match when you expected them to do

Comment: Since `pickedColor` and `clickedColor` are strings, shouldn't you use  [localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) function?

Comment: @Bergi I know that `JSON.stringify` is a very popular fashion for some reason, but personally I find `console.log(pickedColor, clickedColor)` simpler to write.

Comment: @JeremyThille I just wanted to make sure that whitespace gets explicitly formatted

Comment: See my updated answer for a cross-browser and more robust solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log the value that comes back from `this.style.background`, you will see that you get `"rgb(0, 0, 255)"` with spaces after the commas, but that's not how you had the strings in your array. You have: `"rgb(0,0,255)"`. Adjusting those strings to match how the value will come back to you from JavaScript solves the problem in most browsers, but not all. To ensure that the spaces don't become an issue, you can ensure that neither value you are working with has any by manually removing them from your array and then dynamically removing them from the returned JavaScript value:

```js
window.onload = function(){

  var colors = [
    "rgb(255,0,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,0,255)",
    "rgb(182,12,235)",
    "rgb(166,212,166)",
    "rgb(242,123,72)"
  ];

  var pickedColor = colors[2];
  var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
  colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
  var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
  
  for(var i = 0;i<squares.length;i++){
    //coloring each square through colors array
    squares[i].style.background = colors[i]; 
    //listening for a click to compare if true
    squares[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    
        // Ensure that the stored color has no spaces in it by using a regular expression
        // that finds all spaces and replaces them with nothing, essentially removing all spaces.
        var clickedColor = this.style.background.replace(/\s+/g, "");
      
        console.log(clickedColor);  // Logging what you are testing finds the issue.
        
        var op = "rgb(182,12,235)";
        if(pickedColor == clickedColor){
            alert("true");
        }
   });
  }
};
```

```css
.square {width:100px; height:100px; border:2px solid black;}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div id="colorDisplay"></div>
```

Now, using the `style` property of a DOM element can be tricky because it will only return a value if the element has a hard-coded `style` attribute with a value in it in the HTML or if some prior code has dynamically created an inline style on the element.  If a style gets applied to an element via a CSS class, the `style` property won't return that value.

A better technique would be to get the final actual color value that the CSS rendering engine computes for the element, regardless of where or how that style was applied. This ensures that you always get the true value of the CSS property. This is done with the **[`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)** method.

Lastly, it's important to know that the `background` property is a short-hand property that allows you to set many different background related properties all at once, so when you retrieve the value of it, you are likely to get much more than just the background color. To test against a single property, test that property specifically (`backgroundColor`).

```js
window.onload = function(){

  var colors = [
    "rgb(255,0,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,0,255)",
    "rgb(182,12,235)",
    "rgb(166,212,166)",
    "rgb(242,123,72)"
  ];

  var pickedColor = colors[2];
  var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
  colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
  var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
  
  for(var i = 0;i<squares.length;i++){
    //coloring each square through colors array
    squares[i].style.background = colors[i]; 
    //listening for a click to compare if true
    squares[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    
        // Use window.getComputedStyle() for better results

        // Ensure that the stored color has no spaces in it by using a regular expression
        // that finds all spaces and replaces them with nothing, essentially removing all spaces.
        var clickedColor = window.getComputedStyle(this).backgroundColor.replace(/\s+/g, "");
      
        console.log(clickedColor);  // Logging what you are testing finds the issue.
        
        var op = "rgb(182,12,235)";
        if(pickedColor == clickedColor){
            alert("true");
        }
   });
  }
};
```

```css
.square {width:100px; height:100px; border:2px solid black;}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div id="colorDisplay"></div>
```

Comment: This won't work across all browsers. They output the background color style differently.

Comment: Thank you Sir that helped a lot although I'll be reading up on these functions and methods for better practice....:)

It worked

Answer (score -1):

You should create a dataset on the element and reference that.

```
for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {

    //coloring each square through colors array

    squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
    squares[i].dataset.background = colors[i];

    //listening for a click to compare if true

    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

        var clickedColor = this.dataset.background;
        var op = "rgb(182,12,235)";
        if (pickedColor == clickedColor) {
            alert("true");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How does this, in any way, address the problem or solve it?

Comment: @ScottMarcus it creates a data-background attribute into the element that can later be used in the JS. It is a more common and practical way of getting data from a attribute vs attempting to compare the style properties directly.

Comment: The problem is that your answer doesn't meet the OPs use case. You are simply checking the element's background color against a stored version of the element's background color. Of course they are going to match. The OP needs to check against values in an array.

Answer (score -1):

This is really not a reliable method, as you're expecting a very accurate browser output, with spaces exactly at the right place.
But some browsers will give you `rgb(182,12,235)` and others `rgb(182, 12, 235)` and others maybe `rgb( 182 , 12 , 235 )` or even why not `rgba(182,12,235,1)`

You should store your data in an attribute and read from that attribute :

```
squares[i].setAttribute("data-color") = "rgb(166,212,166)"
```

and

```
squares[i].getAttribute("data-color") // This will always be "rgb(166,212,166)"
```

Comment: This does nothing to help the situation, now the string is stored with the element, but it's still in a format that `this.style.backgroundColor` won't match.

Comment: That's precisely my point. Don't use `this.style.backgroundColor`, which is not reliable, but use `this.getAttribute("data-color")` instead.

Comment: You are completely missing that the `data-color` attribute must get its value from somewhere and that somewhere is from the computed CSS value, and that the OP is testing *that* value against a known static set of values. Your example hard codes the `data-color` attribute value, which is not how that value is coming into existence.

Comment: Oh you're right, it's Friday evening, sorry :) In that case, OP should remove all spaces, just to get an ISO format they can check against.